# How to partition a drive that has no partition table without formatting?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I have decreased the size of a partition (at least that is what I believed) using GParted. I now want to use the unallocated space that I got (480 GB) to create an NTFS partition there. However, this drive does not contain a partition table and when running lsblk, no partitions are shown for it.

However, GParted does report that the 'partition' only occupies half the drive now, and shows 3 colors within it, which I thought was not possible.

[Screenshot of GParted right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldgUs.png)

Does anyone have an idea on how to get a partition table on here without formatting the disk? I'll do it if I have to, but I was wondering if there existed an option where I didn't have to.

There is the Device -> Create partition table option, but that will format the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have decreased the size of a partition (at least that is what I believed) using GParted.

There is no partitioning on that drive.
Somehow you/somebody installed an ext4 filesystem on an unpartitioned drive (e.g. the wrong device node, **/dev/sda**).
Then somehow you managed to reduce the size of the filesystem (and not any partition)

> I now want to use the unallocated space that I got (480 GB) to create an NTFS partition there.

That's simply not possible when there is no partition table.
It's drive partitioning that allows more than one filesystem to independently exist on a drive.

> Does anyone have an idea on how to get a partition table on here without formatting the disk?

Creating a partition table *and* preserving an *existing* filesystem is not possible without some special utility (that probably does not exist).
It would (probably) also involve moving the filesystem "backwards", which is a time-consuming task.

The most reasonable (and faster) solution is to make a copy of the existing filesystem (or make an archive of the files), and then start over with a fresh partition table.

> There is the Device -> Create partition table option, but that will format the disk.

Incorrect, creating a partition table has nothing to do with formatting.
Creating a partition table (logically) deallocates everything on the drive.
Partitioning simply defines a contiguous area of the drive for a potential filesystem.
You format (or **mkfs**) a partition in order to install an empty filesystem.

---

The reported drive geometry is bizarre: 2 sectors per track and 3830441 cylinders.
Since the drive is accessed with LBA (rather than CHS addressing) the drive geometry should be irrelevant.
But I'd prefer to see sane values to be reassured that the drive was functioning and setup correctly.
Retrieving the S.M.A.R.T. data could be interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately I already bit the bullet and installed a partition table on the drive (so I can't give you the SMART data you asked for). As you said, I moved important data off of the drive before doing that. Thank you for your answer though, I will accept it since it provides detailed and correct information.